# Unable to connect to elastic search remotely

Tags: elasticsearch

My elastic search is running on server A on port 9200 and 9300.

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      23489/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      23489/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      23489/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      23489/java
```

When I try to connect to elastic search from server B which is on same LAN, I get connection refused error. Even I am unable to telnet the server on port 9200 or 9300. Please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your ES is bound to localhost `127.0.0.1`.

You need to change the `network.host` property in `elasticsearch.yml` in order to be able to connect from remote hosts. Basically, this does the trick and will use the first available IP address in your network:

```
network.host: 0
```